# Nonlinear Ordinary Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, discrete-mathematics, nonlinear-analysis

Does anyone knows if the following equation $$ x'=\frac{t}{x^4}$$ is a nonlinear ordinary differential equation ?

Because usually the nonlinear ODE is of the form $$x'=tx^4$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you set $y=x^5$ then $y'=5 t$ is very much linear and ordinary.

Comment: Sorry but could you clarify what you mean? The x in the equation that i wrote depends on t

Comment: You can make a change of variables (the "variable" here is the function you are after). $y=x^5$ is a bijective change of variables since $5$ is odd.

Comment: Usually when a ODE $x'(t)=f(x,t)$ is referred to as non-linear, it mean that $f$ is non-linear in terms of $x$. So yes, your equation is non-linear. Linear would be something like $f(x,t) = a_0(t) + a_1(t)x + \cdots + a_n(t)x^n$.

Comment: @Hashimoto  here x is the function a function of t $x=x(t)$

Comment: Yes x is function of t. This equation is an ODE and not a PDE.

Comment: Oops, yes I meant ODE. My understanding is that the linear/non-linear classification is performed prior to the solution structure.

Comment: So, are you sure it's a nonlinear ODE? Because usually the nonlinear ODEs are of the form $x'=t x^n$ where $n>1$ but in our case, if you put the $x^4$ in the numerator $n=-4$  so is it nonlinear?

Comment: @E.s.  Is $x \in \mathbb R$

Comment: @Hashimoto Linear ODEs don't involve powers of $x$ higher than 1.

Comment: @Dylan I noticed that I have slightly messed up. Instead of powers of $x$, I should have had derivatives of $x$.

Comment: @callculus Yes $x$ is a function from $t \in R$ to $R$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A first-order linear equation has the form

$$ x'(t) + p(t)x(t) = q(t) $$

Your equation does not have this form, so it is non-linear.

If you're confused by the negative power: It doesn't matter, the equation is linear *only* if it's a linear combination of $x'$ and $x$. For example, all of these equations are non-linear

$$ (x')^2 + \frac{1}{x} =1 $$
$$ x' + \sin(x) = t^3 $$
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{x'}} + \ln(t)e^x = 0 $$

Finally, to address the comments: The changing of variables is irrelevant here. Yes, you can change variables to make a new linear equation, but the original equation in $x(t)$ is still very much non-linear.

Comment: Thanks a lot  for your help! So, relying on what you said, can we say that the equation: $x'=t \sqrt{x^2}$ is a linear equation because the $\sqrt{x^2}$ becomes $|x|$ ?

Comment: $|x|$ is not linear. Unless, you restrict the solution space to $x > 0$ or $x < 0$ then it becomes a linear equation

Comment: Ok, I appreciate your cooperation Dylan :)

Answer (score 1):

An equation is linear when the sum of two solutions is also a solution (to a factor $2$), and non linear otherwise.

$$p(t)x'+q(t)x=r(t)$$ is indeed linear, because

$$p(t)(x_1'+x_2')+q(t)(x_1+x_2)=(p(t)x_1'+q(t)x_1)+(p(t)x_2'+q(t)x_2)=r(t)+r(t).$$

You can check that this doesn't work with

$$x'=\frac t{x^4}.$$

---

Anyway, by setting $y:=x^5$, you can rewrite as

$$y'=5t,$$ (provided $x\ne0$) which *is* linear.